# Unconclusive RandomForest documentation in ScikitLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

In the ensemble methods documentation of Scikit-Learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#id6 in section *1.9.2.3. Parameters* we read:

> (...)  The best results are also usually reached when setting max_depth=None in combination with min_samples_split=1 (i.e., when fully developing the trees). Bear in mind though that these values are usually not optimal. The best parameter values should always be cross- validated.

So what is the difference between best results and optimal? I thought that by best results the author means best cross-validated prediction results.

> In addition, note that bootstrap samples are used by default in random forests (bootstrap=True) while the default strategy is to use the original dataset for building extra-trees (bootstrap=False).

I understand this in the following way: bootstrapping is used by default in Scikit-Learns implementation but the default strategy is to *not* use bootstrapping. If so then what is the source of the default strategy and why is it not the default in the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the first quote is self-contradictory. Maybe the following would be better:

> The best results are also often reached with fully developed trees (max_depth=None and min_samples_split=1). Bear in mind though that these values are usually not guaranteed to be optimal. The best parameter values should always be cross-validated.

For the second quote, it compares the default value of the `bootstrap` parameter for random forests (`RandomForestClassifier` and `RandomForestRegression`) to extremely randomized trees as implemented in the classes `ExtraTreesClassifier` and `ExtraTreesRegressor`. The following might be more explicit:

> In addition, note that bootstrap samples are used by default in random forests (bootstrap=True) while for building extra-trees the default strategy is to use the original dataset (bootstrap=False).

Please feel free to submit a PR with the fix if you find those formulations clearer to understand.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clear. Please let me know what a PR is then I will do it :)

Comment: PR stands for "pull request". It's the standard way to contribute to an open source project hosted on github.com